# Error en computed properties Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

Tengo la siguiente Alert:

```
<w-inline-alert
              v-else
              alert-type="warning"
              :alertTitle="i18nTexts.programmedEmailTitle1"
              :alertText="i18nTexts.sendLink + this.cartDetail.recovery_url"
              icon-class="w-alert-uploading"
              show
            />
```

y en computed agregue parametros para poder incluir las funciones que necesito ademas del texto predeterminado. (es la primera vez que lo hago asi)

```
computed: {
    i18nTexts () {
      return {
        programmedEmailTitle1: 
        this.translateText('Enviaremos un email recordatorio al cliente para que retome la compra el :dateReturn a las :dateTime',{
          dateReturn: this.cartDetail.will_send_at.date,
          dateTime: this.cartDetail.will_send_at.date
        }),
```

El problema que me surge es que me toma :dateReturn  y :dateTime como  [object Object]  y no los valores que deberia mostrar de mi modelo de datos.

que estoy haciendo mal? deberia agregar el parseData que tenia anteriormente? o como deberia hacerlo correctamente?

agrego la funcion en JS que me toma los parametros para que vean que valores trae.

```
this.getText = function(baseText, parameters) {
        var translatedText = baseText;
        var found = false;
        if (this.langDictionary != null && typeof this.langDictionary[baseText] != 'undefined' && this.langDictionary[baseText]) {
            translatedText = this.langDictionary[baseText];
            found = true;
        }

        if (typeof parameters == 'object') {
            for (var key in parameters) {
                translatedText = translatedText.replace(new RegExp(':' + key, 'g'), parameters[key]);
            }
        }

        /* Agrego el texto en el sistema de traducciones */
        if (!found && typeof Data != 'undefined' && Data.System.Environment == 'dev' && this.pendingSave < 15) {
            var self = this;
            self.pendingSave++;
            $.post('/home/ajaxText', { text : baseText }, function() {
                self.pendingSave--;
            });
        }

        return translatedText;
    }
```

aqui la funcion de TranslatedText para ver que valores trae:

```
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    $_translate_i18nHelper () {
      if (!window.i18nHelper) {
        /**
         * Utilizo el objeto window para hacer referencia a los plugins
         * que se encuentran fuera del proyecto wobiz-vue.
         */
        window.i18nHelper = new window.InternacionalizationHelper()
      }
      return window.i18nHelper
    }
  },
  methods: {
    translateText (text,parameters) {
      return this.$_translate_i18nHelper.getText(text,parameters)
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Revisaste el valor de i18nTexts  en tu navegador? parece un objeto...

Comment: esta funcion translateText donde esta y que valor toma this.cartDetail.will_send_at.date??

Comment: añado la funcion de translate y la de getText @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví con:

```
this.translateText('Enviaremos un email recordatorio al cliente para que retome la compra el :dateReturn a las :dateTime',{
          dateReturn: this.$_parseData_date(this.cartDetail.will_send_at),
          dateTime: this.$_parseData_date(this.cartDetail.will_send_at)
        }),
```

dentro de las computed properties.