# Mostrar formato Hora con JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, parsear

Tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
$_parseData_time (data) {
      var d = new Date()
      var time = ( /(\d+)(?::(\d\d))?\s*(p?)/ )
      d.setHours( parseInt( time[3] ? 12 : 0) )
      d.setMinutes( parseInt( time[2]) || 0 )
      return d
    }
```

Estoy intentando que me devuelva la hora formateada en un componente de Vue que pueden ver en la pregunta anterior

> [Error en computed properties Vue](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/262170/118416)

pero me trae tambien lo siguiente:

Fri May 10 2019 00:00:21 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time)

como deberia corregirla para obtener solo el horario?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con `solo el horario`?

Comment: Exacto @Aprendiz solo deseas mostrar horas, minutos y segundos

Comment: con puro JS o usando algo como moment.js?

Comment: deberia con puro js @Aprendiz y modificando o utilizando solo esa funcion del parseData que muestro aqui

Comment: respuesta actualizada

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx pero necesitaria utilizarlo dentro de la funcion que puse, porque tengo todo un archivo con distintos parseData y desde ahi se utiliza

Comment: ah vale, por curiosidad, ¿conoces momentJS?

Comment: no @fredyfx pero tampoco puedo linkearlo o utilizarlo en este proyecto, solamente modificar esa funcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una mezcla interesante entre VueJs y MomentJS

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [         
      new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 3, 31, 0),
      new Date(2017, 10, 23, 11, 13, 2, 0),
      new Date(2016, 9, 22, 12, 34, 40, 0),
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    moment: function (date) {
      return moment(date);
    },
    date: function (date) {
      return moment(date).format('hh:mm:ss');
    }
  },
  filters: {
    moment: function (date) {
      return moment(date).format('hh:mm:ss');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.method {
  color: grey;
}

.filter {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
      <p>{{ moment(item).format('hh:mm:ss') }}</p>
      <p class="method">{{ date(item) }}</p>
      <p class="filter">{{ item | moment }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo, tienes 2 métodos y un filtro para formatear los datos en horas minutos segundos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví con:

```
$_parseData_time (data) {
      var d = new Date()
      var h = d.getHours();
      var m = d.getMinutes();
      return h + ':' + m
    }
```

Comment: ¿En qué momento utilizas el parámetro `data`?